# How is it possible to obtain delta function in the degenerate perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

$$H = H_0 + V(t), V(0) = 0$$

Let $|i_0\rangle$ be the eigenstates of $H_0$, i.e. $H_0|i_0\rangle = E_{i_0}|i_0\rangle$, and $|i(t)\rangle$ is $|i_0\rangle$ after a time $t$ (with hamiltonian $H$).

If $V(t) = V^*\cos(\omega t)$ , we have a well-known result when $t\rightarrow\infty$:

$$\langle f_0|i(t)\rangle = \frac{2\pi i}{\hbar}V^*(\delta(\omega_{f_0} - \omega_{i_0} + \omega) + \delta(\omega_{f_0} - \omega_{i_0} - \omega)).$$

So, how is it possible? If we represent $|i(t)\rangle$ as $\sum_{i_0} C_{i_0} |i_0\rangle$, $C_{i_0}$ can't be a delta function, due to a unit norm at least.

Comment: A sum being delta doesn't imply that one of its coefficients has to be. See $\sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty e^{inx} = 2\pi \delta(x)$.

Comment: But there the  coefficients  ARE delta functions

Comment: You need a continuous spectrum for this result to be true.

Comment: Yes, but in many cases H_0 have a discrete spectr. Atom, for example. I have an idea, that |i_0> isn't a basis anymore, but i don't know exactly